# Is publishing yet another RPG system a good or bad idea?

Tags: indie-rpg, publishing

The situation is this: I recently designed an RPG system with a group of friends (a sort of mad-lib type system, an improv-type system where you can't say no but just take what the player and/or GM say and move forward and develop the setting from there).

Now, I have done some basic research and have come up with no systems that are seemingly similar or identical. However, I'm not sure if people would even consider playing it or care about it unless it was super spectacular, considering there are already so many out there. **Would people potentially be interested in my RPG? Should I pursue this further and publish it?**

Comment: Please clarify your question and try to make it more factual less opinion.  "Is it a good idea" elicits cage opinion only.

Comment: @mxyzplk Fact: there is always room for yet another RPG. I don't see that there's any opinion involved here, just a person who is very unfamiliar with the state of independent RPG publishing who requires a reality-check.

Comment: The only point I'd still like to know about is whether there's any intention to publish, or if the question is whether its worth keeping on making an RPG just to be played between friends.

Comment: This question still needs editing with more information as to the questioner's intents/concerns. "A bad idea" in terms of making money? Yes. "A bad idea" in terms of vanity in the indie game scene? No. "New game yes or no" is still 100% opinion based without criteria, so this is closed as opinion based.

Comment: "How do I get interest in my game?" and "How do I get help in writing an independent RPG?" are both possibly quite good indie RPG questions, which you could feel free to ask separately. Generally, you should only be asking one distinct question per question, since you don't have a limited budget of questions you can ask.

Comment: @user3092062 I'm going to edit your last paragraph out of your question and edit the remainder a little bit. If you'd like to discuss this issue with us, please [join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) - you now have the reputation to do so. We can talk about what you can do about asking this stuff here. In the question itself isn't really the place for discussions and voicing objection, but we can talk about it there.

Comment: The question is more about what resources do I have available then actual help itself because from what I am getting so far from this forum is that the original question is to opinion based, and the original question was about generating general statistics of whether something like this would be worth my time to flush it out and actually make it functional and useable for other people.

Comment: @Alan if you're looking to use this question as a vote/poll sorry, we don't do that here.  We answer questions that look to solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 10):

If you're developing your own RPG and you and your friends enjoy it, that's great! If you want to play a particular way, and creating your own thing to let you play that way is what makes you happy, then there's nothing you need to worry about. There's nothing wrong with developing another, whether it's for yourself or others - that isn't a bad thing at all, and quite a worthwhile pursuit if you care to do it.

In case you're worried people might think *"we don't need another one of those!"* - they won't. To give you some perspective, RPGGeek lists [almost 4,500 RPGs](http://rpggeek.com/browse/rpg) - and there are plenty of fun ones that wouldn't be listed there, like [Roll for Shoes](http://story-games.com/forums/discussion/11348/microdungeons-i-roll-to-see-if-i-have-shoes-on/). Nobody is going to be upset that there's another one, and might be pretty happy if it seems like they'd have fun with it!

Comment: In fact, there are lots of people who actively seek out new RPGs because they like to try new ways of roleplaying, so for those people they will be actively happy to hear about a new game published.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course, you should.

But a few words of warning... First and foremost, expect to do a lot of work on it: writing is not the same thing as playing with friends. You must make it all understandable and clear to complete strangers.  Also, friends are great play testers but not nearly sufficient. Nor are they proof readers. Second, do expect people to criticise everything about your system.  If you are lucky, they will do it in an [assertive way](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Assertiveness-Work-Practical-Handling-Situations/dp/0077114280) but expect "you suck" a lot and sometimes they might just be right despite being obnoxious. Know as well, that you cannot please everyone. Finally, do not expect to get rich from it. You will not. Remember [Yog's law](http://www.sff.net/people/yog/) at all times which states that *[money flows towards the writer](http://neil-gaiman.tumblr.com/post/23090050950/for-novice-writers-the-quick-test-for-are-you-being)*.

All that gloom and doom said: **go for it!**  If nothing else, it will give you an experience.

Comment: You have nothing to lose, but also know there are a *ton* of games out there with more and more appearing monthly.  If you publish do it out of a labor of love for your game. As Sardathrion said don't expect to get rich.